# How to control the redirection of a request, once a host changes a DNS server

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, dns-zone, dns-hosting

I'm sorry if this question is too broad, but I'm not sure where to get started. Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

a) I am trying to set up my own private nameservers (say n1.example.com and n2.example.com). Let's say you own example.com and you change your namservers to these 2.

b) Now, once you do that, in most hosting providers, you are usually presented with some page (like, you've successfully migrated to us, blah blah).

I want to be able to CONTROL that page (have a web app in the background that will accept these requests). Now, I'd prob need to go at a very lower level than having a VPS for this.

a) Do I need my own DNS server? Can I simply use a vanity private name servers?

b) More importantly, once someone changes the name servers to mine, HOW DO I CONTROL what happens when someone lands on their homepage?

Please excuse me, once again, this may be a more general question than needed, but I really don't know how to start here or what things to familiarize myself with.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need my own DNS server?

No. Unless you're a DNS expert (which you're not, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question), you should not even consider hosting your own DNS.

> Can I simply use a vanity private name servers?

Don't bother. No one cares. Really. No one cares. Use a well-respected DNS host (Route53, Google Cloud, Namecheap, etc.). You'll not be wasting time maintaining your own DNS, but it will also be orders of magnitude more reliable than anything you could come up with on your own.

> More importantly, once someone changes the name servers to mine, HOW
>   DO I CONTROL what happens when someone lands on their homepage?

You have a wildcard record in the domain, pointing to the IP address of your webserver, which is configured to accept requests for the domain(s) in question and respond to the requests with whatever custom content you require for that domain.

> Now, I'd prob need to go at a very lower level than having a VPS for
>   this.

Why do you say that? Serving a web page in response to an HTTP request is exactly what a webserver on a VPS would accomplish.

Comment: You're on a roll today with good answers. Slow day at the office? :)

Comment: Hah, no just a couple worth answering during my lunch break. :)

Comment: @EEAA I don't understand how a website like http://nameserver.io/ can work then, they seem to be using Route53 in the background), you just generate the nameserver URL and you enter it as your nameserver, and everything works magically.